# what is the best practice for creating auto generate IDs

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I have to maintain the purchase details for my company in single table, there are three Purchase dept that are involve in purchase and they are maintaining there own 'Purchase order SlNo'....

hence i cant use Auto increment number and I should have to use something like,

```
X-001
X-002
```

all belongs to only first dept

```
Y-001
Y-002
```

all belongs to only second dept

```
Z-001
z-002
```

all belongs to only third dept

Can any One suggest me out and suggest the best practice?
(Using C#).

Comment: *creating auto generate IDs* If they're auto-generated you don't need to create them.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCompany
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CompanyID AS 'X-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblCompany` without specifying values for `ID` or `CompanyID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCompany(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CompanyID` will contain values like `X-00001`, `X-00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

PS: I don't know where you get the `X-`, `Y-` etc. prefixes from - you'll have to adapt this solution (with a fixed prefix) to your own situation (with changing prefixes), but the basic solution remains the same: let SQL Server handle the auto-numbering (that's the only viable way to do it), and then just add your extra stuff using a computed, persisted column.

Comment: *SQL Server will automatically and safely increase your ID value* What happens if there's 100000 records...

Comment: @ta.speot.is: if you need to support more than 100'000 rows - you'll need to use more than 5 zeroes in the `RIGHT` function ....

Comment: I quoted the wrong part. *CompanyID will contain values like X-00001, X-00002,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.* The example code could produce duplicates. It could be improved to use some algorithm that would go from `X-99999` to `X-100000`. But I +1'd you at the start, since your answer is pretty much correct.